# How to know the ContentTypeId of a content type made with the Sharepoint interface?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, content-type

I am working on a workflow in VS which creates a task with content type.
The content type I want to use is a custom content type made with the SharePoint interface.

Is there a way to know this content type's Id so I can use it in my workflow?

If not; is there an alternative how to initiate a task containing this content type with my workflow code in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the ID of the content type in the url when looking at a content type in "Site Settings > Site Content Type Gallery". The url will be something like:

http://litwaredemo/_layouts/ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=0x010132165465465464654654654

The last part is the Content Type Id.

Answer (score 0):

[You can download SharePoint Manager.](http://www.codeplex.com/spm)

This will allow you to view all the content types in a given site collection.  The properties (inlcuding Id) are listed.

You can also do loads more with this it's an invaluable tool for SharePoint admins.

**Note:** This needs to run on a server within your farm, if you don't have access then this is not the solution for you.  But maybe your admins could run it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have made my own SharePoint development testing server environment so I have access.

I've downloaded SharePoint Manager and using it now. Indeed, not only the features are visible but also the contenttypes inside the webapplication.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worth noting then that if you recreate your content type in a live environment you will need to change the workflow to use the new content type id.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a nice tool but all of this information is also available in SharePoint Designer, if SPDesigner 2010 is allowed in the environment of course.

Also as a last resort perhaps in a no install environment, you can go directly to the list enable allow management of content types and in the URL at the end in the ctype="" query string parameter you will see the content type (you can also get the lists guid aka unique ID this way). just remember to turn off "allow management of content types" if you do not want the end-users messing with the schema of the content type.

Thanks,
SG.